# OWIN OpenIdConnect middleware - set RedirectUri dynamically

Tags: owin, middleware, openid-connect

Is there any way how can I set RedirectUri property for OpenIdConnectMessage based on a Request scope, not Application scope?

My app is serving multiple domains (myapp.com, myapp.fr, ..) and based on domain, it determine default language for the content. I need that the user is taken back to the same domain after login thru IdP so I need to find a way how RedirectUri is set per request scope rather than app scope as done by configuring middleware options in startup.cs .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be done via `Notification` event `RedirectToIdentityProvider` . Something like this:

```
 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                 {
                     RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
                     {
                         n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = n.OwinContext.Request.Uri.Host;
                         n.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = n.OwinContext.Request.Uri.Host;
                     },
                     //other notification events...
                 }
```

`

Comment: you saved me, i totally forgot about events. i had to dynamically change clientId.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm working on a legacy .NET framework 4.7.2 app. I'm trying to use this approach to dynamically set the `RedirectUri` inside RedirectToIdentityProvider, but it causes an Exception `Error: 'invalid_grant'. Error_Description (may be empty): 'Incorrect redirect_uri'.` However it works fine if I only set the `RedirectUrl` property on app startup in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`. I can't find any other references online to altering the RedirectUri causing this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a note for anybody reading Chris's comment above: this error is coming back from the identity provider, so it means that the application and the IdP is not configured to accept the redirect_url parameter passed in the HTTP request and the beginning of the flow.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken`, it's necessary to set `RedirectUri` in several notification events.

In the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` notification, you can set the `RedirectUri` on `TokenEndpointRequest` to ensure the same value is also passed in the token request.

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
{
    n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUrl;
    // other settings   
}
```

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = n =>
{
    n.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri = redirectUrl;
    // other settings   
}
```

Comment: This was the fix for me.  I was using ProtocolMessage in both and there was no redirecturi in the request.  Changing AuthorizationCodeReceived to TorkenEndPointRequest made it work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post and the answer is already mentioned. But it still took me a while to figure out how to set the dynamic RedirectUri.

I was assigning RedirectUri in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions and RedirectToIdentityProvider, which was causing issues.

We should assign RedirectUri only in RedirectToIdentityProvider event.

For someone who needs help, you can check my code [here](https://github.com/iHarshalAgarwal/DotNetSamples/blob/main/KeycloakOpenIdConnectAuth.cs)

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your site to Microsoft Azure with multiples domains pointing to the same site and turns on: *Authentication-> Allow unauthenticated access* (your site have public and private pages); Microsoft Azure randomly call back one of your Redirect URIs. To control this random behavior, you need to explicit set *RedirectUri* property base on Owin Context Request.

[image]

Don't ask me why, also you need to change URIs address removing *“.auth/login/aad/callback”* except for localhost. (If anyone knows the reason for this please let me know)

**This works code works for me:**

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        string strPostLogoutRedirectUri;
                        string strRedirectUri = EnsureTrailingSlash(context.OwinContext.Request.Uri.ToString());

                        int nPos = strRedirectUri.IndexOf("://");
                        if (nPos > 0)
                        {
                            nPos += 3;
                            strPostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://" + strRedirectUri.Substring(nPos, strRedirectUri.IndexOf("/", nPos) - nPos + 1);
                            strRedirectUri = strPostLogoutRedirectUri;
                            if (strRedirectUri.Contains("localhost"))
                            {
                                strRedirectUri = strPostLogoutRedirectUri + ".auth/login/aad/callback";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strRedirectUri = "https://YOURSITE.com/";
                            strPostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://YOURSITE.com/";
                        }
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = strRedirectUri;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = strPostLogoutRedirectUri;
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            );

        // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }

    private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = string.Empty;
        }

        if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return value + "/";
        }

        return value;
    }
```