# Setting up IdentityServer openid authentication on runtime

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, identityserver3

My tech consists of net core app, identityserver 3.

I am using IdentityServer for authentication purposes.

I am trying to set up the new instance of OpenIdConnectOptions.

Is there a way I can set this up on runtime in Startup.cs or only through appsettings.json.

Current set up is:

```
var openIdConnectOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions()
            {
                ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:OpenIdAuthentication:ClientId").Value,
                Authority = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:OpenIdAuthentication:Authority").Value,
                CallbackPath = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:OpenIdAuthentication:CallbackPath").Value,
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                SignInScheme = "Cookies",
                AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                AutomaticChallenge = true
}

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConnectOptions);
```

The thing is I am using cookie and loading some settings in context based on different cookies, which changes clientId, so I need to set up ClientId on runtime, before `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConnectOptions);` invokes.

Is that possible in Startup.cs ?

Comment: The step you are asking about in `Startup.cs` only happens once, on application initialization. Therefor you can't change the settings based on the cookie in each request. There would be a security issue in there somewhere, I'm sure. Why are you changing the context based on a cookie?

Comment: I am changing design template for 2 different clients on one webapp hosted. They are accessed with different subdomain, and proper cookie is set up based on subdomain. Different cookie loads different Client settings, that will be passed to SSO identity server. So I was thinking if there is a way to dynamically set up this, without hosting same app on two different webapps,.

Comment: This is an issue I encountered, same web app with two different branding skins, unfortunately, we had to go with side by side hosting of the same app as we could not get around this configuration problem. I don't know of another solution

Comment: I think I found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645178/owin-openidconnect-middleware-set-redirecturi-dynamically . I can change clientId before request is done initially here in event, trying other parameters as well now.